# solving a trigonometric equation 1-cos(180°-x)+[(sin180°+x)/2]=0 .

Tags: trigonometry

$1-\cos(180^{\circ}-x)+\left(\frac{sin(180°+x)}{2}\right)=0$
Can someone help me on solvinf it.
I did $1-(-\cos x) + \left(\frac{sin(180°+x)}{2}\right)=0 $

Comment: $ \ \sin (180º + x) = -\sin x \ $ .  Have you covered linear equations in sine and cosine?  Otherwise, the likely expression would be **lab bhattacharjee**'s interpretation, and you have what becomes a quadratic equation in cosine.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\cos(180^\circ-x)=-\cos x$$

If you have meant $\displaystyle\sin\frac{180^\circ+x}2,$ it is $$=\sin\left(90^\circ+\frac x2\right)=\cos\frac x2$$

Finally use [Double Angle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html) formula on $$\cos x=\cos\left(2\cdot\frac x2\right)$$

Comment: When i came to this : 1+cosx+√[(1+cosx)/2] what to do then?

Comment: @dona12, follow the other way: $$1-(-\cos x)+\cos\frac x2=0\iff 1+(2\cos^2\frac x2-1)+\cos\frac x2=0$$ which is a quadratic equation in cosine

Comment: Why its (2cos^2 x/2 -1)

Comment: @dona12, have you noticed the link in the answer?

Comment: Yes but i dont know how and why...anyway thanks for help.

Comment: @dona12, set $2y=x,$ in $$\cos2y=2\cos^2y-1,$$

Comment: But when we have cosx how can we take formula for double angel cos^2x?

Comment: @dona12, can 't we write $$\cos x=\cos(2\cdot\frac x2)$$ or $$\cos x=\cos(3\cdot\frac x3)$$  for that matter?

Comment: Yes because we get the same result x

Comment: Can i ask just one another question,i'm trying in another way i have -1-t, i have to square it (-1-t) but if i write -(1+t)^2 that minus before it drops or not?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13251/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-dona12)