# simplify this expression $1+\cos x+\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}{2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$1+\cos x+\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}{2}}=0$$
Can someone help me to solve

I tried with a quadratic equation but I can't get the right result.

Comment: It looks like you want to *solve the equation*, not "simplify that expression" ...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687511/solving-a-trigonometric-equation-1-cos180-xsin180x-2-0

Answer (score 4):

$$1+\cos x+\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}{2}}=0\implies 1+\cos x=2+4\cos x+2\cos^2x\implies$$

$$2\cos^2x+3\cos x+1=0$$

The above quadratic (in cosine) discriminant is

$$\Delta=9-8=1$$

so you get

$$\cos x_{1,2}=\frac{-3\pm 1}{4}=\begin{cases}-1\\{}\\-\frac12\end{cases}$$

Solve thus $\;\cos x=-1\;,\;\;\cos x=-\frac12\;$ ...and **remember** afterwards to check the possible solutions *in the original equation* since we squared and things can go wrong with this (why?)

Comment: Antonio $\cos x = -\frac 12$ isn't solution. You need to plug the solutions to check them.

Comment: @Stefan4024, didn't I write exactly that at the end of my answer...?

Answer (score 2):

Note that: $$\sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos x}{2}} = \cos \frac x2; \quad \text{for}  \quad  \cos \frac x2 \ge 0$$

From this we have: $1 + \cos x = 2 \cos^2 \frac x2$

Now just substitute and we have:

$$2\cos^2 \frac x2 + \cos \frac x2 = 0$$
$$\cos \frac x2 \left(2\cos \frac x2 + 1\right) = 0$$

Now solve it.

Comment: Careful, that equation is only true for some $x$, because $\cos \frac x 2$ can be negative...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I mentioned at the end $\cos \frac x2 > 0$

Comment: Much much later (and in odd syntax - it's difficult to understand if you are asserting something or suggesting that you need it. Also, of course, it could be $=0$....

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes I admit it would have been better to mention that at the beggining.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem to have a solution other than $1+\cos(x)=0$ you need to consider the "other" square root, viz, the negative square root. In this case
$$
1+\cos(x) = \frac 1 2
$$
works if you are willing to fudge the definition of square roots. If not there is no solution other than $1+\cos(x)=0$